# SQL: get rank of a data set after sorting data

Tags: sql, sorting

I have a simple table that contains unique identifiers and a counter value for each of them. What I need to get as result is the position of a specific identifier after the table was sorted by the counter values.

My current solution would be to do a SELECT for all data while sorting the result, then going through the result list to find the required identifier, the position where I find it is the ranking value I want to get.

Unfortunately this requires much memory and computing time for large tables. So my question: is there a SQL statement that returns the position of a specific identifier after the table was sorted?

Comment: **Which database** and what version are you using?? "SQL" is **not** a database system - it's just the Structured Query Language that many database systems use. These kind of things are often vendor-specific, so we need to know your environment.....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using SQL Server 2005 and newer, you can use the `RANK()` or `DENSE_RANK()` windowing functions:

```
SELECT
   (your list of columns here),
   RANK() OVER(ORDER BY yourcolumnnamehere)
FROM dbo.YourTable
```

or:

```
SELECT
   (your list of columns here),
   DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY yourcolumnnamehere)
FROM dbo.YourTable
```

See [explanation of difference between RANK and DENSE_RANK here](http://geekexplains.blogspot.com/2008/06/difference-between-rank-and-denserank.html)

Other RDBMS (like Oracle) also seem to support those windowing functions.

Comment: You can add [PostgreSQL 8.4+](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/functions-window.html) to the list, window functions are awesome.

Comment: Do you know if it's possible with MySQL ? Thanks